# NPM uninstall doesn't uninstall dependencies

Tags: node.js

I have noticed in some experiments that `"$ npm uninstall --save --save-dev X"`, does not uninstall dependencies that only X depends on. Is there a way to uninstall all the modules that only X depends on when you run the above command?

Answer (score 4):

There is a command to remove unnecessary packages:

`npm prune`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune